# Can't find field data in Sharepoint list using SOAP

Tags: 2013, xml, soap

I'm stuck trying to find some data in a Sharepoint list.

I have the list ID, using the List Service `GetList` method I can see that the field I'm looking for is attached to the list. When I try to use `GetListItems` the field isn't there.

I've been assuming that it means the field I want isn't in the default view, but even when I define the view fields explicitly or change the query, I still can't find the data. What should I do?

Here's my best effort at this point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:GetListItems>
         <ns1:listName>{1A8A3DF2-E5D0-4DDE-B31A-CCC2FB7DA90F}</ns1:listName>
         <ns1:viewFields>
            <ViewFields>
               <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
               <FieldRef Name="Project_x0020_Description"/>
               <FieldRef Name="Style_x0020_number_x0020_quantit"/>
               <FieldRef Name="Requirement"/>
               <FieldRef Name="First_x0020_order_x0020_entry_x0"/>
               <FieldRef Name="MKT_x0020__x0025__x0020_Completi"/>
               <FieldRef Name="MFG_x0020__x0025_Completion"/>
            </ViewFields>
         </ns1:viewFields>
         <ns1:rowLimit>10</ns1:rowLimit>
      </ns1:GetListItems>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

If I include only fields that are part of the default view, I get the default view of the list back.

If I use `ViewFields` to limit the result to fields not in the default view, the server times out.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<ns1:GetListItems>
 <ns1:listName>{1A8A3DF2-E5D0-4DDE-B31A-CCC2FB7DA90F}</ns1:listName>
 <ns1:rowLimit>10</ns1:rowLimit>
 <viewFields>
       <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
       <FieldRef Name="Project_x0020_Description"/>
       <FieldRef Name="Style_x0020_number_x0020_quantit"/>
       <FieldRef Name="Requirement"/>
       <FieldRef Name="First_x0020_order_x0020_entry_x0"/>
       <FieldRef Name="MKT_x0020__x0025__x0020_Completi"/>
       <FieldRef Name="MFG_x0020__x0025_Completion"/>
 </viewFields>   
</ns1:GetListItems>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.

I tried your suggestion, but it gave me the default view without some of the specified fields.  I don't understand why it ignores the FieldRef fields.